# probability and Set Theory (subset)

Tags: probability

$X$  and $Y$  are sets which are independent and uniformly chosen from all $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,...,n\}.$

Determine $\rm{Pr}(X ⊆ Y).$

any ideas?

Comment: How big are $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 3):

This should be $(.75)^n$. One way of thinking about it is that each element of the set has a $.25$ chance of being in $X$ but not in $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $(2^n)^2=4^n$ equally likely ways to choose an ordered pair $(X,Y)$.

We now count the favourables, the ordered pairs such that $X\subseteq Y$.

For any $k$, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ sets $X$ of cardinality $k$. For any such set, there are $2^{n-k}$ choices for $Y$. Thus the number of favourables is
$$\sum_0^n \binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}.$$
By the Binomial Theorem, this sum is $3^n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $X'$ (complement of $X$) have $k$ elements $0 \le k \le n.$

There are then $n$ choose $k$ choices for $X'$ and the set $Y$ must include $X$ and some subset of $X'$, so that each contributes $2^k.$ So using the binomial theorem, we get $3^n$ for the total number of ways $X \subset Y.$

The total number of ways to just choose a pair of subsets is $2^n\cdot2^n=4^n,$ so that the probability comes out $3^n/4^n=(3/4)^n$ as in Scott's answer.

Comment: So the probability that is X is a subset of Y is  (3/4)n?

Comment: @Joe Yes, $(3/4)^n$ which is in agreement with both Andre's answer (having the same argument) and with Scott's "intuitive" answser.